# Interesting XSL Dilemma

Tags: xml, xslt

I've got this issue.

A template called "checkbox" that's called from while inside a table HTML element and also outside of it.

To solve an issue, I've added `<td>` tags to "checkbox" input control.

Here's what I'd like to do to but I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

When I hit my "row" (part of the custom table markup) template, I would set some variable or pass some parameter, that for each template applied afterwards, would know it was in a "row" and do something special based on this information. I know I can't add parameters to apply-templates. I may be able to add a row "mode" but I can't make changes to each template and have one copy with the mod parameter and one without.

Thanks for any suggestions. I know the ideal solution would to be to make changes to the XML but I'm not sure if I can do that as this point. That's a "content" issue. :P

Thanks!

***Addendum:***

I'm going to try to better explain my issue.

I have this template called "checkbox". Sometimes I need a  tag surrounding the call that renders the checkbox, sometimes I do not. The times I do the "checkbox" template are when its parents are called by a "row" template's call to apply-templates (this translates to a , thus the need for the  for the checkbox forum control).

The problem is I need to be able to reuse the checkbox template in both cases: 1) When it's not being called by a row template and when it IS being called by a row template.

I hope this is clearer.

Comment: I know why this is important but sometimes it's just not reasonable to do so. I can't post whole chunks of code from our code base onto the internet and while I can come up with a simpler example, often problems are hidden in what's surrounding it. That's why I went with a length text explanation.

Comment: Are you saying that my text explanation isn't good? I think posting code would be way more confusing. Do you have any questions for clarification other than "post code"? I'll try to come up with some clever way to demonstrate the problem without posting huge chunks of code, but I'd rather put that effort into explaining the problem clearly.

Comment: I for one can't make head or tail of your text explanation.

Comment: Good question (though more details would make it really a proper one), +1. See my answer for an explanation how to avoid parameters or modes for solving such a simple problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hit my "row" (part of the
>   custom table markup) template, I would
>   set some variable or pass some
>   parameter, that for each template
>   applied afterwards, would know it was
>   in a "row" and do something special
>   based on this information. I know I
>   can't add parameters to
>   apply-templates. I may be able to add
>   a row "mode" but I can't make changes
>   to each template and have one copy
>   with the mod parameter and one
>   without.

**To begin with, parameters *can* be passed to templates** that are selected for processing by an `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction. Do read about `<xsl:with-param>`.

**However, passing such a parameter isn't usually needed**. Here is an example:

If a template matches a specific (current) node and it must act in a special way depending whether this node is within a table row, then it is a matter of a simple check:

`parent::tr`

**selects the parent node only if it is a `tr`.**

`ancestor::tr`

**selects all ancestor `tr` nodes**.

In case the first or the second XPath expressions above selects a non-empty node-set, then (respectively), the parent of the current node *is* a `tr`, or the current node is within some `tr`.

**So, you may use an `<xsl:when>` to test this**.

**Here is how a complete solution may look like**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="checkbox">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="ancestor::tr">
     <myTag><xsl:copy-of select="."/></myTag>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
  <checkbox>1</checkbox>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><checkbox>1</checkbox></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<checkbox>1</checkbox>
<myTag>
   <checkbox>1</checkbox>
</myTag>
```

**Very often conditional instructions can be completely eliminated by specifying specific templates with predicates in the match pattern**. If you provide the necessary relevant information, people might be able to publish an elegant solution.

Comment: I'm using <xsl: if test="ancestor::table">

Comment: Its giving me the desired results but I'm not allowed to put <td> or any html tags in the if statement. I'm sure there's a way around this but not sure of it atm.

Comment: @bobber205: You *can* have `td` (or any other markup) inside of an `<xsl:if>`. I would use a `<xsl:choose>` and two `<xsl:when>` instructions inside it to deal with the two separate cases. Read more about `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:if>` or ask a new question with this specific problem -- the prevailing majority on the xslt tag can provide you with the right answer.

Comment: @bobber205: I edited my answer and now it contains a complete example.

Answer (score 2):

You can call a template with a particular “mode”:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="row"/>
```

But it is also possible to apply templates with parameters:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*">
  <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="'row'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

The latter approach works at least if all templates that might match the elements they are applied to ('*' in this case) declare a parameter named 'mode'.

Comment: Does the second code sample apply all templates and only pass the mode attribute to the row template?

Comment: "The latter approach works at least if all templates that might match the elements they are applied to ('*' in this case) declare a parameter named 'mode'." This is specifically what I cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

> When I hit my "row" (part of the
>   custom table markup) template, I would
>   set some variable or pass some
>   parameter, that for each template
>   applied afterwards, would know it was
>   in a "row" and do something special
>   based on this information. I know I
>   can't add parameters to
>   apply-templates. I may be able to add
>   a row "mode" but I can't make changes
>   to each template and have one copy
>   with the mod parameter and one
>   without.

These are limitations of XSLT 1.0, solved in XSLT 2.0 through new `mode` handling and tunnel params.

In XSLT 1.0 you can have the "poor man's tunneling" overwriting the "any element" built-in rule like:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:param name="mode"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:with-param name="mode" select="$mode"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Do remember to progate this pattern to your rules matching more specific elements.

Comment: Can I pass a mode to JUST the checkbox template in the apply-template function?